# Moq Method called by System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Factory.StartNew

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, moq

I am using Moq to write a unit test.  I have a DataManager object which calls WCF to fetch data.  I inject this into my controller.  however inside the controller the call to the Method in this DataManager is wrapped inside of a Task

```
System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Factory.StartNew<MyDataObject>(()=>
{
   return DataManager.GetMyDataObject(userobj, recordid);
}
```

I have created a mock for the  DataManager.GetMyDataObject with Moq
but whenever it is called from this statement inside of the controller method
it returns null.  I have googled alot but most of the stuff out there are dealing with methods which have Task as the return signature.

The DataManager.GetMyDataObject is written as standard sync code.

I am using Moq v4.0.10827 and doubt I can upgrade.

I am trying many ways..Moq seems to expect the return to match the method signature

```
_mockDataManager = new Mock<_mockDataManager>();
_mockDataManager.Setup(m => m.GetMyDataObject(It.IsAny<UserObj>(), It.IsAny<Guid>()))
```

and well then returns?  I also trid callback

```
        _mockDataManager.Setup(m => System.Threading.Tasks.Task.FromResult(m.GetMyDataObject(It.IsAny<UserObj>(), It.IsAny<Guid>())
            .Returns(System.Threading.Tasks.Task.FromResult(myData))
            .Callback<MyDataObject>(o => myData = o);

        myData = GetMyDataObject();
        _mockDataManager.Setup(m => m.GetMyDataObject(It.IsAny<UserObj>(), It.IsAny<Guid>()).Returns(GetMyDataObject())

private GetMyDataObject() {
 returns new DataSet();  //basically an empty dataset but not null
}
```

Comment: How is `DataManager.GetMyDataObject` and how did you mock it? Show us that code.

Comment: Is `DataManager.GetMyDataObject` a static call?

Comment: _mockDataManager = new Mock<DataManager>();

Comment: no it is not static method or class.  It is an instance which is injected into the controller

Comment: What I've done in the past when requiring `Task.Factory.StartNew` is to create a adapter for this with an interface. Essentially this just calls `Task.Factory.StartNew` underneath but also allows you to mock the call to `StartNew`. This is because we didn't want any tests to start new tasks, but at the same time wanted to make sure that our code would actually call `StartNew`, synchronous and testable.

Comment: I just need any call to _mockDataManager.GetMyDataObject() to return an something whether it is called with a Task or just normally.  I don't know how to do this.

Comment: I seriously doubt the mocking issue is related to the task. The task is not part of the equation because the interface you mock returns `MyDataObject`, not a task. The last Setup+Return is the one to go with. I see two potential reasons why your mocking fails: either the method in question gets parameters which are not UserObj + Guid, but some other type. Or, you didn't actually inject your mock to your controller as you believe. Test those two assertions, if not, then post more code...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given the following classes:

```
public class MyDataObject { }

public class UserObj { }

public class DataManager
{
    public virtual MyDataObject GetMyDataObject(UserObj userObj, Guid guid)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}

class SUT
{
    public DataManager DataManager { get; private set; }

    public SUT(DataManager dataManager)
    {
        DataManager = dataManager;
    }

    public void Method(UserObj userobj, Guid recordid)
    {
        var t = System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Factory.StartNew<MyDataObject>(()=>
        {
            return DataManager.GetMyDataObject(userobj, recordid);
        });

        t.Wait();
    }
}
```

the following mock works fine:

```
var mockDataManager = new Mock<DataManager>();
mockDataManager.Setup(m => m.GetMyDataObject(It.IsAny<UserObj>(), It.IsAny<Guid>()));
var sut = new SUT(mockDataManager.Object);
sut.Method(new UserObj(), Guid.Empty);

mockDataManager.VerifyAll();
```

---

Two pitfalls:

In the code you posted, you use

```
_mockDataManager = new Mock<_mockDataManager>();
```

which should be

```
_mockDataManager = new Mock<DataManager>(); // or whatever the name of the class is
```

Maybe this is just a copy/paste error, maybe not.

Also, since you use a `Task` here:

```
System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Factory.StartNew<MyDataObject>(()=>
{
   return DataManager.GetMyDataObject(userobj, recordid);
}
```

which calls `GetMyDataObject` on `DataManager`, you have to make sure that the `Task` finished *before* you verify your mock setup. If you would remove the `t.Wait();` from my code above, the test would fail, because `VerifyAll` would be called before the `Task` would start and call `GetMyDataObject` in the mocked object.

Comment: Thanks.  It was a typo, and actually I did have Task.Wait().  It turned out that the Returns() of my Mocked method which was returning a dataset was not working or something.  Not too sure now as I immediately started googling into much more complicated async tests.  Thanks this helped me focus on the simple essentials and I got it sorted.